# Unrealised/unrealisable - synonyms

Tags: synonyms

A person's potential, given their strengths was unrealised - attributable to their character.

"Unrealised" reminds me of utility, both sounding cold and business-oriented.

Are there more personal, less formal words like unrealised that also carry more a more implicit worth - so for example, the person above is not devalued? (Even if mention of the character seemed to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unrealized/unrealisable are two different uses of unrealized. If one has not accomplished their goals then their goals are still unrealized. The goals that cannot be reached no matter who by or how long they are sought are unrealisable.

I don't know of *Unrealized* goals reflecting on or being attributable to ones character except in novels. In your experience it may sound cold and business-oriented but it is merely accurate. One's subjective experience comes into play here.

Other characterizations of goals that have not or perhaps cannot be reached are *Lofty* as in a loft, the higher spaces in a barn or building. They could be *Over Ambitious* or even *Unrealistic*. Worthy ambitions might be undreamt of goals, those they would not even dream of reaching.